# ffmpeg: how add watermark to all video outputs?

Tags: shell, video, filter, ffmpeg, watermark

I have a simple code that takes my video files (in my folder) and converts them to 480x360:

```
for %f in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -i "%f" -vcodec libx264 -s 352x240 -acodec copy -f mp4 "%~nf-240p.mp4" -vcodec libx264 -s 480x360 -acodec copy -f mp4 "%~nf-360p.mp4"
```

It works correctly, but I want to add a watermark with the following options:

```
-i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10"
```

After adding these options:

```
for %f in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -i "%f" -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" -vcodec libx264 -s 352x240 -acodec copy -f mp4 "%~nf-240p.mp4" -vcodec libx264 -s 480x360 -acodec copy -f mp4 "%~nf-360p.mp4"
```

it just adds watermark on 240p.mp4. How do I apply this filter to all files?

Thanks.

Comment: In which shell do you run this command? Please tag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
for %f in (*.mp4) do
    ffmpeg -i "%f" -vf "movie=watermark.png[wm];[in][wm]overlay=10:10"
           -vcodec libx264 -s 352x240 -acodec copy -f mp4 "%~nf-240p.mp4"
                  -vf "movie=watermark.png[wm];[in][wm]overlay=10:10"
           -vcodec libx264 -s 480x360 -acodec copy -f mp4 "%~nf-360p.mp4"
```